# ASP.NET membership provider with EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have been using ASP.NET membership provider the way it comes and it s been just fine serving my basic purposes. One thing I realize is that, it installs bunch of Stored Procs etc to the database.

Is there a EF implementation of ASP.NET membership ? or will there be?

I have an up coming project which i will need to extend the functionality of the Membership providers with roles and authorization via some GUI.

Moreover, everytime I use this, I have two connection string in my web.config one for DbContext one for Application services particularly for Membership provider. Why cant i have just one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are gui membership management systems for MVC3 you can take a look at or add to your project.

- [Asp.Net MVC Membership Starter Kit](https://github.com/TroyGoode/MembershipStarterKit)
- [Security Guard](https://github.com/kahanu/Security-Guard/wiki/1.--Overview)
- [More](http://nuget.org/packages?q=membership)

You can play around with them and see how they work. It's simple once you know where to look and you can create your own.

The [Membership Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.aspx) and [MembershipUser Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.aspx) holds all the user info. For example to un-approve a user you can do this:

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser("userName");
user.IsApproved = false;
Membership.UpdateUser(user);
```

And if you want to delete a user, you can use `Membership.DeleteUser("userName");`.

The [Roles Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.aspx) has all the role associated info. Like `Roles.GetUsersInRole("roleName")` will return a list of all the users in the role `roleName`. `Roles.CreateRole("roleName");` will create a role, and `Roles.DeleteRole("roleName");` will delete a role.

If you need more than just the default, you can look at [Implementing a Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

As far as having two databases, this is not necessary. You can add all the ASP.NET tables, stored procedures, etc. to your database by using the `Aspnet_regsql` tool. Take a look at [Installing the Database using Aspnet_regsql.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). This will allow you to only have one database, so you can remove the asp.net connection string in your `Web.Config` and then change the `AspNetSqlMembershipProvider` `AspNetSqlProfileProvider` `AspNetSqlRoleProvider` and maybe others, to use the connection string to your main database.

Answer (score 2):

The universal providers are what you are looking for: http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core

These are implemented using EF Code First 5 internally, we will be making the internal DBContexts public once we make sure everything works smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.NET membership provider and Roles implementation in Entity Framework, need to import all views of ASPNETDB (Membership database) in EDMX file. e.g. vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers, vw_aspnet_Roles, vw_aspnet_UsersInRoles, vw_aspnet_Users, etc...

Then Membership will be run via EF. So, You can provide GUI using below functions.

here is controller code. e.g.

```
  // GET: /Membership/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
    {
        var recordToEdit = (from r in _db.vw_aspnet_Users where r.UserId == id select r).First();
        return View(recordToEdit);
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_db.vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers.ToList());
    }
```

Now, How to merge the ASPNETDB to existing Database, to make only one connection string in web.config. (Your question: Why cant i have just one?)

That is also possible using below steps.

ASPNETDB.MDF is membership provider database and is used for storing and retrieving
membership data from database and here we are going to see how to create membership provider database . The command used to create Aspnetdb.mdf is ASPNET_RegSQL.EXE

1.Start->Programs->Microsoft visual studio 2005->visual studio tools->Visual Studio 2005 command prompt. Type ASPNET_RegSQL.EXE in the visual Studio 2005 command prompt

1. A wizard with the heading ” Welcome To The Asp.Net Sql Server Wizard ” will be displayed. Here need to click Next
2. Next a wizard with ” Select Setup Option ” will displayed. Now we need to select setup option “Configure sql server for application purpose is default”. Select which one you wants and next.
3. A window with ” Select Sql Server Database ” Will be shown Now we need to select our sql server database. Here needs to set server, authentication type and database.
   If select the default name”aspnetDb.mdf” will be selected. If you wants to modify existing database select that database.

5.Now A confirm will be displayed with heading “Confirm your Settings”. Now check servername and database name and click next.

1. A window with ” The database Has Been Created Or Modified ” Will displayed. Now click Finish

Be careful in above steps you need to select your existing database, Some tables (11+), views, stored procedures of Membership and Roles will be added to your existing database....

Enjoy it....Thank you...

Comment: For Code First approach, Non-query commands can be sent to the database using the ExecuteSqlCommand method on Database. context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand( "<Your Membership SQL>");

Comment: well not interested in sql queries or stored procs. who is using those anymore?